# Java Servlet throws 404

Tags: java, servlets

Hey Guys iam trying to make a simple Java Servlet that returns a JSON. The web.xml is in the WEB-INF directory and i checked already if i typed in the link false or something like that.
Here is my ServletClass:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet(name = "BetaAuthServlet", value = "/betaAuthServlet")
public class BetaAuthServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String message = "Test";
        out.print(message);
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>BetaAuthServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>de.hanimehagen.tridentdevelopment.betaauth.BetaAuthServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>BetaAuthServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/BetaAuthServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When i lounch the App an go on localhost:8080/betaAuthList i got a 404 error. Iam not realy sure if i need a index.jsp but i think i dont need it. The Tomcat server should work fine. It would be very nice if someone could help me.
Greetings Hagen

I found a solve for my problem:
I used Tomcat Version 10. After i used Version 9 it works!

Comment: Hi & Welcome! the WEB-INF directory .... of "ROOT" (or which) application? Where is the compiled class? How did you "introduce" it "to tomcat"?

Comment: ..when you do `@WebServlet`, you don't need to/no web.xml. Here is a ["nice tutorial/article"](https://www.javaguides.net/2019/02/webservlet-annotation-example.html) ..just "package" that @webservlet into a "war" and deploy it.

Comment: Your `@WebServlet` and web.xml show the path as `/BetaAuthServlet` or `betaAuthServlet` - paragraph at end states you're trying to get `/betaAuthList`?